# Technique culinaire où on glisse une farce sous la peau

Tags: vocabulaire, alimentation

En cuisine, comment s'appelle la technique qui consiste à insérer une herbe, un champignon, ou une garniture sous la peau de la pièce de viande?

Un plat connu réalisé ainsi est la poularde demi-deuil.

Comment: Toute la beauté de la question tient à ce que ça ne doive *pas* être fermé car *trop localisé* ^_^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cela s'appelle *[contiser](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/contiser)* et s'applique  à deux techniques similaires:

- glisser la garniture sous la peau,
- inciser la viande ou le poisson pour y insérer la garniture, ou faciliter sa cuisson